# Getting the textbox value

Tags: php, yii

I'm really new to Yii and as a starter, I want to know how to get the value from the textbox when the button is pressed.

```
<?php CHtml::textField($name,$value,array('submit'=>'')); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Greet!',array(
             'submit' => 'message/goodbye')); ?>
```

Comment: You can get value using jquery with textbox name/id/class

Comment: set an id for that input and select it using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UNDERSTANDING THE BASIC CONCEPT

You have to remember that Yii is an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) ( Model, View Controller ) and the best practice is to keep the entire structure like so. The best way to learn it is from the awesome forum that they have.

Hence, to define a scenario where you would like to save a data/textbox from the form, you would be following the following workflow :

### **A BASIC WORKFLOW**

*Assuming that you don't want to save the data in the Database.* :

I would be assuming that a basic knowledge of the how the framework works is known. You can check out the guide and the other tutorials if not.

This is a basic workflow in which the data would be taken from the form and validated in the model.

1. Create a model file in your `protected/models` folder

Example : Lets name this file as FormData.php

```
<?php

class FormData extends CFormModel{
    public $name;
    public $email;


    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('name , email','required'), // This rule would make it compulsory for the data to be added.
            array('email','email'), // This will check if the email matches the email criteria.
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'name' => 'Enter your name',
            'email' => 'Enter your email',
        );
    }

}

?>
```

2. After this , in your `protected/FormController.php`

Add this :

```
<?php

class Formdata extends CController{
    public function actionCoolForm()
    {
        $model = new FormData();
        if(isset($_POST['FormData'])){
            $model->attributes = $_POST['FormData'];
            if($model->validate()){
                // Do whatever you want to do here.
            }
        }

        $this->render('someview',array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
?>
```

3. Now to add the form in your page is easy :

```
<?php echo CHtml::form('formdata/coolform','post'); ?>

<?php 

echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'name');
echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'email');

?>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

### **Now to add it in the database**

The best and the easiest method of adding it in the database is to use the Gii.
But the code is nearly identical, except that the model extends CModel.

I hope that I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your view some thing like

```
        <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'aForm',
            'htmlOptions' => array('onsubmit'=>"return false;"),
                ));
        ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('name', 'value'); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Greet!', array('onclick' => 'getValue()'));?>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And the Action Script for the onclick event is

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getValue()
            {
                $text=$("#aForm").find('input[name="name"]').val();
                alert($text);
                //$formData=$("#aForm").serialize();
            }
        </script>
```